# What is the purpose of the tags preceded with a [dot]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a number of tags preceded with a `.` that appear to be just file extensions. For example [.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.java), [.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.js), [.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.csv), [.mov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.mov), [.wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.wav), etc.

There are also corresponding tags without the `.`. For example [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), ([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)), [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv), [mov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mov), [wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wav).

What is the difference between these tags? Is there a case where the [.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.java) tag should be used and not [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)? or [.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.csv) and not [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv)? Can someone explain the use case?

Comment: It looks like in most cases these tags are already synonyms. [.java] is a synonym of [java] etc. Except for [mov] which is an assembler instruction while [.mov] is about quicktime movies.

Comment: Are synonyms ever removed? is there value in having a java and .java tag?

Comment: I would discourage the use of language extension tags, but the media or generic file extension tags might be useful when the question is about generating or parsing said file type.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree, why is there a [.java] and [.js] tag when there's not (nor should there be) [.py],[.rb], [.css]... ad infinitum

Comment: @mhatch Since the tags are synonyms if the synonym is used on a question it will be silently replaced with the parent. eg. [.java] is replaced with [java]. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: @Kara So, if the tag synonyms are silently replaced with the canonical version, is there a point when the synonym becomes effectively unused? Shouldn't then be removed if it doesn't add anything helpful?

Comment: @mhatch Would the be any benefit in removing the synonym? Even if it is very rarely used I think it would be better to silently replace it with the parent tag then to allow users to re-create it as a separate new tag.